# How Can I Change The Style Of A Div On Mousedown?, or any other event for that matter…

Tags: javascript, html, css

But it doesn't work. You can see I'm trying to change the class of the div containing season.png onmousedown and revert it onmouseup.

What am I missing?

Thanks.
Mike

Comment: does the original winter spring class display? because maybe your name selector is incorrect ? could you post that part of your code

Comment: this is working code, we do you mean by "it doesn't work" ???

Comment: First of all, thank you to everyone for your help.

The scary truth: Neither style is in a CSS rule or file. I'm relying on two very large javascript files (that I didn't write) to make them work. I am guessing, in this case, it's simply not possible to switch the class to something else.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The Javascript file I was using was a very inflexible library. I solved the problem a different way.

Answer (score 2):

It's working just fine. There is nothing wrong with the code that you posted, so if you can't see it there has to be something wrong with your css.

I used this to test the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style>

.winter { border: 1px solid blue; }
.spring { background: yellow; }
.summer { background: green; }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="winter spring" onmousedown="this.className='winter summer'" onmouseup="this.className='winter spring'">
<img src="Resources/season.png" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me so I guess you need to run some checks on your code. Make sure your css is included.

Post the complete code you are using so we can look for errors.

This is the code I used:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>onmouseevents on div</title>
        <style type="text/css">
body
{
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: #000;
}
.page
{
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 640px;
}

.winter
{
    background-color: cyan;
}
.spring
{
    color: magenta;
}
.summer
{
    color: yellow;
}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page">
            <div class="winter spring" onmousedown="this.className='winter summer'" onmouseup="this.className='winter spring'">
                Cats!
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.summer{ background-color:red;}
.spring{ background-color:blue;}
.aa{ font-size:18px;}
.bb{ font-size:36px;}
</style>
<div class="aa spring" onmousedown="this.className='summer aa'" onmouseup="this.className='spring bb'">
aaaaaaaaa
</div>
```

I test this code, it works well.
I think, not javascript problem. Try to check css, or other things.

Maybe put js code and css code on the **img** is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative - I have used the hover pseudoselector for this.

Here's a personal example:

```
.sidebar ul.sidebuttons li a
        {
         font: bold italic x-large/1.1 trebuchet ms,verdana,sans-serif;
         display: block;  /* effect should be in a new box not inline */
         text-decoration: none; /* turn off link underlining */
         color: yellow;
         background: black url(sidebar_off.png) no-repeat center;
         padding: 10px 10px 10px 5px;
         margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
         border: white outset;
         border-width: 2px 2px 2px 0px;
         text-align: right;
         text-transform: lowercase;
        }

.sidebar ul.sidebuttons li a:hover
        {
         background: yellow url(sidebar_on.png) no-repeat center;
         color: black;
         border: black inset;
         text-decoration: none;
         border-width: 2px 2px 2px 0px;
        }
```

The HTML looks like:

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <ul class="sidebuttons">
    <li><a href="somelink.html" title="A linke">Go Somewhere</a></li>
```

If you're having trouble, try Firefox Web Developer add-on or something similar to check the style information on that part of the page. It might not be triggering what you think it should be triggering.

Answer (score -1):

It's very easy with [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery):

```
$(".winter").mouseup(function() {
    $(this).addClass("spring");
    $(this).removeClass("summer");
},function(){
    $(this).addClass("summer");
    $(this).removeClass("spring");
});
```

Comment: As that does the same thing as the code in the question, that doesn't work either, as the problem is somewhere else...

Comment: Note that's actually more verbose than the original code, which many people have noted is correct.  And the OP has shown no interest in JQuery.

Comment: Since when is previous interest in jQuery a precondition to answering a javascript question with a jQuery solution?

I also disagree about verbosity, since the jQuery solution would work for all divs in the page with the "winter" class. So he doesn't need to inline all that javascript into every single div.